# A button don't responding. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have very very small code, where I describe behavior of button. But it don't react.

**JS**:

```
$('.boxbar').click(function(){alert('Click')});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="boxbar">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.boxbar
    text-align: center
    padding-bottom: 16px
    padding-top: 12px
    height: 58px
    cursor: pointer
    [class^='box']
    color: $primary_font_color_W
    background: $primary_color_bg

    &:hover
        background: $hold_color
        color: $primary_font_color_B
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please also note that there is a **lot** of information about how to format your question on the Ask a Question page. It's well worth your time to take a moment to make your question as clear and properly-formatted as possible.

Comment: The problem is probably this: [*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) But the question isn't clear enough to be sure.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: works fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWzJWY

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score -1):

First off the i tag is depreceated, use em. SECOND,Your div has no text or visual element value, it takes no real estate in the browser so you'll need content in the em tag to have something to react to your alert function.

Comment: Do you realize that is how font awesome works? http://fontawesome.io/examples/ It is an inline block element with a width so there is something to click.

Comment: Cite reference for `<i>` being deprecated

Comment: My bad, look like you are missing curly brackets {  and semi colons ;  in your CSS

Comment: Why did i get a vote down, i have solved their isse, which was a css syntax error

Comment: Being that this work with regular CSS there must be either a jQuery Library missing or some sort of sass problem, because there's nothing wrong with the JavaScript